# How to profile Eclipse plug-in startup time?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiling, eclipse-juno, eclipse-tptp

I'm trying to profile an Eclipse plugin, specifically it's start-up time. I'm not terribly familiar with Eclipse nor its profiling tools, and it seems that plugins are somewhat of a special case: I tried using [JVM Monitor](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/), but it cannot seem to detect the JVM running on localhost (even after I made sure to run the JDK instead of JRE and other things suggested in the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/)). I then found a [guide for profiling plugins with TPTP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Profiling_with_TPTP_-_plug-in_development), but as I understood TPTP is no longer maintained and isn't even available for the latest Eclipse release, Juno.

Any tools, preferably simple to setup, to let me profile the startup time of my plugin?

Comment: `start-up time`? Do u mean whether this plugin is lauched or not?

Comment: Yes, all the methods called during launch and the time spent in them. The exact situation is, I'm working with some huge files and startup takes >5 mins, so I'm trying to find the bottleneck before I start optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

I like using [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/). They have very good Eclipse integration.  It is not free, but well worth the cost if you will be doing lots of profiling.

Comment: This is the right tool. As you want to get an overview of all plugins interacting together, the OSGi console will not help you that much.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has been OSGi-based since 3.0.
Just use an `SS` console command in the OSGi console view to check the bundle(your plugin) status.
See more [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-osgiconsole/).